# MonoTouch Comparing Strings

Tags: unicode, string, compare, xamarin.ios

I have an app which lists many languages. In the app I compare language names.

When I compare language names with no accents it works and the compare is true.

When I compare languages with accents, it doesn't think they are equal.

In this case they are NOT equal (but should be).

```
Language = "Español";
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString s = new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString(Language);
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString l = new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString ("Español");
```

In this example they ARE equal (notice no accents).

```
Language = "Deutsch";
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString s = new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString(Language);
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString l = new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString ("Deutsch");
```

I have tried cultureinvariate compares to no avail.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

I am using MonoTouch 1.4.4

Comment: where is your actual code which does the compare?

Comment: if(s==l) {....}   This works in .NET in Visual Studio, but not in MonoTouch which makes me think it might be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following matches as you require ignoring accents:

```
var Language = "Español" ;
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString s = new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString(Language);
MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString l = new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString ("Español");

int result = String.Compare(s,l, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```